# How do I Convert a FormattedText String into a Geometry-Based Object?

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-3.5, geometry, formatted-text

How do I convert a FormattedText string into a geometry-based object?

I don't think this question requires much explanation, and I can't think if very many other details I could give ...

I just need to convert the FormattedText into something I can use mathematically (geometrically).

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`FormattedText.BuildGeometry Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext.buildgeometry.aspx) or [`FormattedText.BuildHighlightGeometry Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext.buildhighlightgeometry.aspx); both MSDN links are featuring the usual examples too.

The basic usage pattern is like so:

```
// Create sample formatted text.
FormattedText formattedText = new FormattedText("Sample",
    CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"), FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
    new Typeface("Verdana"), 16, System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black);

// Build geometry object that represents the text.
Geometry normalGeometry = formattedText.BuildGeometry(
    new System.Windows.Point(0, 0));

// Build geometry object that represents the highlight bounding box of the text.
Geometry highLightGeometry = formattedText.BuildHighlightGeometry(
    new System.Windows.Point(0, 0));
```